# Function not working on any file other than the main plugin file

Tags: plugin-development, functions, hooks

My plugin has several php files that are included on the main plugin file. I am using some functions on the other files but they don't work there. They work when I use them on the main plugin file.

For example,

**On the main plugin file *"test-plugin.php"***

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test Plugin
Description: test
Version: 1.0
*/

include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'test-file.php' );
```

**On the other file *"test-file.php"* (same directory with test-plugin.php)**

```
<?php

function enable_user_registration() {
    if(!get_option('users_can_register')) {
        update_option( 'users_can_register', '1' );
    }
}

register_activation_hook( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__), 'enable_user_registration' );
```

Regards..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should be using `register_activation_hook()` with the full path including filename, not just the path:

```
register_activation_hook( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'test-plugin.php', 'enable_user_registration' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `register_activation_hook()` is the **plugin filename including the path**, so you need `__FILE__` instead of `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`.

```
// This should be in main plugin file
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'enable_user_registration' );
function enable_user_registration() {
    if(!get_option('users_can_register')) {
        update_option( 'users_can_register', '1' );
    }
}
```

It is common to register the activation hook in the main plugin file, but **the callback can be defined in any file you wish**.

For example, in test-file.php you can define the callback:

```
function enable_user_registration() {
    if(!get_option('users_can_register')) {
        update_option( 'users_can_register', '1' );
    }
}
```

And in the main plugin file you can register the activation hook:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Test Plugin
Description: test
Version: 1.0
*/

include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'test-file.php' );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'enable_user_registration' );
```

You could also store the value of `__FILE__` from the main plugin file in a constant, so you don't need to harcode any file name or file path:

```
/*
Plugin Name: Test Plugin
Description: test
Version: 1.0
*/

define( 'MY_PLUGIN_FILE_PATH', __FILE__ );
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
include_once( MY_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . 'test-file.php' );
```

And then, in test-file.php:

```
register_activation_hook( MY_PLUGIN_FILE_PATH, 'enable_user_registration' );
function enable_user_registration() {
    if(!get_option('users_can_register')) {
        update_option( 'users_can_register', '1' );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the answer I already gave. Just you forgot, that this code is inside `test-file.php` and not inside the main plugin file. But the plugin activation will call the hook with the main plugin filename. See my answer.

Comment: O yes, I didn't notice. Just a few minutes of difference, It seems I was written while you published your answer. As far I understand the source code of `register_activation_hook()`, the plugin activation will call the hook with any passed filename; not sure if passing a different filename can have negative consequences, but I guess not, I've seen how big and well known plugins use this method, as well in several development books.

Comment: When a plugin is activated, the action 'activate_PLUGINNAME' hook is called. In the name of this hook, PLUGINNAME is replaced with the name of the plugin, including the optional subdirectory. Quote from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) So the hook is always called with the main plugin file name. register_activatio_hook won't throw an error if you use some other name, but the result is, that your function will not be called as it is hooked with the wrong tag.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but actually my answer is correct, maybe the comment was not correct but the answer is.

Comment: Yes, of course. My comment was just in response to your comment.